# Pass arguments to Execute method in Custom Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, configuration, node.js, custom-activity

Hello I am having a little issue, I am using a template I found online, [this](https://marketingautomation.isobar.ch/2020/12/07/journey-builder-custom-activity-deep-dive/), I have hosted it and it is working properly when it comes to ethds executiion and so on :

The issue is That I am trying to get now rows attribute from Data extesnion and I am not receiving any, I am receiving only the Subscriber Key via the CONTACT.KEY code, but nothing much, the CONTACT.KEY was already there in the template

So what I have tried to add is the inArguments in the config.json file, I tried to retrieve the age & country of the CONTACT with no success

```
"arguments": {
    "execute": {
      "inArguments":[
        {
          "age": "{{Contact.Attribute.age}}",
          "country":"{{Contact.Attribute.country}}"
        }
      ],
      "url": "https://hello-domain.herokuapp.com/journey/execute",
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "format": "json",
      "useJwt": false,
      "timeout": 10000
    }
  },
```

I have tried this in my execute method just to see what is in there :

```
var aArgs = (JSON.stringify(req.body.inArguments[0])).substring(1,490);
```

And result was :

```
{"contactKey":"3409995c-a495-4687-949d-0c3b22be14de"}
```

I tried to find out why this and then found the save methd had this :

```
function save() {
    //if($form.valid()) {
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [
            {
                "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
            }
        ];

    ...
    ...

}
```

So whenever I am saving my journey, data can be retrieved in here but how can I access the DE ?

I tried this :

```
function save() {
    //if($form.valid()) {
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [
            {
                "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
                "age": "{{Contact.Attribute.testing_AUT.age}}",
                "country": "{{Contact.Attribute.testing_AUT.country}}",
            }
        ];

    ...
    ...

}
```

No success, my attribute are empty and my logs is this RN :

```
{"contactKey":"3409995c-a495-4687-949d-0c3b22be14de","age":"","country":""}
```

Then tried this, this is the doc :

```
function save() {
    //if($form.valid()) {
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [
            {
                "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
                "age": "{{Contact.Attribute.age}}",
                "country": "{{Contact.Attribute.country}}",
            }
        ];

    ...
    ...

}
```

And finally this :

```
function save() {
    //if($form.valid()) {
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [
            {
                "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
                "age": "{{Contact.Attribute.Age}}",
                "country": "{{Contact.Attribute.Country}}",
            }
        ];

    ...
    ...

}
```

But again not working, so can I access my attributes ?

ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was that I wasn't mapping the DE in Data designer, it worked when I did that.

Go to Data designer & add Attribute Group and map your DE subscriber key to Contact key and here's your solution.

Code won't work even though it is syntaxally correct.

Comment: +1 for coming back after finding a solution yourself and adding an answer that could be helpful to future seekers.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the inArguments should be an array of key-value pairs, not an array with one object:

   ```
   "inArguments": [
    {
      "emailAddress": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "{{Contact.Default.PhoneNumber}}"
    }
   ]
   ```

This is how it is done in this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/example-rest-activity.html).

2. There might be an issue with the data binding as well. Are you able to access the first name on the contact?

   ```
   "inArguments": [
    {
      "firstName": "{{Contact.Attribute.Persona.FirstName}}"
    }
   ]
   ```

Please review the section "fully qualified attribute names" under Contact Builder Context [How data binding works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/how-data-binding-works.html) to determine how to access age and country. You might need to add it to the contact model as done with the "PhysicalAddresses" in the example.

Comment: Solution was that I wasn't mapping the DE in Data designer, it worked when I did that, thanks, I hope someone sees this comment so he/she does not forget to do the mapping..

Comment: @TaouBen - feel free to post an answer to your own question, describing your solution. Putting it in an accepted answer makes it easier for the community to find relevant answers.

Comment: @LukasLunow Correcr, i'll do it